# Reduce name length in ASP.Net Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, webforms

I'm trying to reduce ASP.Net page size now. I've successfully reduced ID's length, but have a problem with classic names of ASP.Net controls.

For example, 
`<input type="hidden" name="ctl00$mainContentPlaceHolder$repeaterListView$ctl03$ProductListSearchPanel1$hiddenfieldProductId" id="hiddenfieldProductId" value="24052" />`

What features or ways I can use to reduce length of name in ASP.Net?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Could you explain the issue you are having? I am guessing it's not purely that the names are too long. Are you having issues with ViewState being too large as there are ways to increase postback size etc rather than going down this route.

Comment: I have a lot of products on the page and I need them to be indexed by google (100kb limit). So reducing control names will be useful.

Comment: Woah, ok so your question really should be totally different! How about "How can I optimise my ASP .NET website containing lots of products so that Google can index it" or something along those lines? Then you could add "I've tried reducing the name of the controls..." - People will probably give you lots of ideas such as not going down the path you've taken! You probably want an index or other mechanisms rather than it looking through all of your controls. Just an idea.

Answer (score 3):

Setting the `ClientIdMode` attribute of server controls will usually make the id more readable and consistent. (`ClientIDMode="Static"`)

Comment: I think you need to be careful with this approach though. If you have two user controls (UserA and UserB) and both have a button named (ID) "OK" then I think you will have two controls with the same ID which could cause issues? You could name each item with Page + ID but then you start going back up in size and as per my comment, what is the OP actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @Acro - Yes, I said "named" to make it easy to understand my meaning but put ID in brackets for clarify, maybe a mistake. That being said the IDs will be duplicate which can cause all sorts of issues. How would you know which ID actually corresponded with which control if they both have the same ID? What are YOU actually trying to achieve as per my question to your original question? Are you getting ViewState errors? No-one will really care what your controls are called under the bonnet so there must be a reason why you are trying to do this?